# Loading serilog configurations from appsettings.json file in a .netframe work web application

Tags: web-applications, serilog, .net-4.8

Can serilog configurations be loaded from appsettings.json file in a .net framework web application instead of web.config.

Would like to explore on adding hooks for including headers in the log file. I am unable to add it using web.config hence looking for appsettings.json

Below configuration works with console application but fails with error in a web application.

```
       var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
```

can this code be added in Global.asax file application_start method.

Error in web application-

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link answered my question - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-serilog-in-asp-net-core-web-api/

Instead of appsettings.json, included a seri-log.config.json in the application

Worked code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;

.
.
 var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile("seri-log.config.json").Build())
.CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Please mention the link as Reference below the answer